A snow covered remote town, murder investigation, glass chalet struggle
For about a year I've been trying to remember a film. I don't think it was a dream but I've had no leads so I'm starting to feel I might have made it up.
In the film, there's an actor, in a snow covered remote town, and I think he's there investigating murders. I remember him being in a shack at one point, and in my head the guy looks like Daniel Craig (all though I'm pretty sure it wasn't him.)
What I remember most clearly is near the end of the film, there is a big glass chalet, I think there's a safe, and there's some kind of struggle in the house.
Please help me find this film, if it really does exist, it's driving me nuts!!!

Hm, assuming it was not a dream, what genre do you connect with your memorys, Horror, SciFi, Thriller? Some parts of it would fit some films, but it is not much information to go on. Knowing how old the film is or any other details would also help.

I think this is the English language version of The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo (2011) with Daniel Craig.
When Blomkvist (Craig) is hired to investigate a death of a girl (and, as it turns out related deaths) he is put up in an old cabin (apparently with really good wifi) on an snow covered island that is the family home of the dead girl.

Blomkvist agrees to investigate the disappearance and assumed murder of Henrik's grandniece, Harriet, 40 years ago. After moving to the Vanger family's compound, Blomkvist uncovers a notebook containing a list of names and numbers that no one has been able to decipher.


Toward the end of the fill, Craig confronts the putative villain at his chalet.

Blomkvist breaks into Martin's house to look for more clues, but Martin catches him and prepares to kill him. While torturing Blomkvist, Martin brags of having killed women for decades but denies killing Harriet. Salander arrives, subdues Martin and saves Blomkvist. 


This is a real house, Villa Överby by John Robert Nilsson on the outskirts of Stockholm, Sweden. 
More images
